# FUNCTION REPLACE IN A FUNCTION IN SQL

Tags: sql, function, replace, char

I need to build a function to replace vowels in a string of characters: A->4, E->3, I->1, O->0, U-> 7

This is what I have, but it's not correct:

```
CREATE or ALTER FUNCTION Punto11
(
@replace char (20)
)
RETURNS char
AS 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @PALABRA char (55) ='ola'
    SELECT @replace =  REPLACE (REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@PALABRA,'a',4),'E',3),'I',1),'O',0),'U',7)
    where @replace like @PALABRA
RETURN @replace
END
GO
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Which DBMS, is it SQL Server? And what logic are you trying to capture, that `WHERE` is rather odd

Comment: Try SET instead of SELECT

Comment: "Not correct" in what way? Please explain ( as edit to your post)

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use the "where" construction in you example? Does it work for you?

```
CREATE or ALTER FUNCTION Punto11
(
@replace varchar (20)
)
RETURNS varchar (20)
AS 
BEGIN 
    SELECT @replace =  REPLACE (REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@replace,'a',4),'E',3),'I',1),'O',0),'U',7)
RETURN @replace
END
GO
```